# resharper ignore specific issue

Tags: c#, resharper

A Resharper newbie question:

I've run "Find Code Issues" which gave me a bunch of issues. There are plenty of issues that I agree with Resharper's suggestions but there are some where I'd like to keep the code as it is. Once, I make a decision on an issue I don't want it to appear again in the issues list so that I don't need to reconsider it again unnecessarily.

Is there a way suppress the suggestion after I make a decision on an issue. I know there is suppress with comment function but it clutters the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(I'm assuming you're talking about individual *instances* of violations.)

Suppressing with a comment sounds like the best approach to me. You claim it clutters the code, but I think it documents the decision appropriately. It communicates with your team-mates that you've *thought* about the issue, as well as why you've come to the conclusion that you have.

If you find you're having to do this frequently, that suggests you may want to change the code analysis settings to globally suppress certain suggestions/warnings.

Comment: I agree with you, but unfortunately "suppressing" is solved a bit ugly in R#. To suppress a message at a certain position, a comment is added before and after that statement. That makes code less readable.

Comment: @Fischermaen: Having it both before and after is unfortunate, certainly - although similar to the language-level `#pragma warning disable`. But it should be a rare situation IMO.

Comment: You're right, it should be rare. But I would prefer having a suppression mechanismn similar to the on of FX Cop; giving you the chance to have the suppressions collected in one file.

Comment: @Fischermaen: But then it's not clear when you're *reading* the code. *If* you've got the global settings written appropriately so that there are reasonably few comments (a few per file at most) then I think it makes perfect sense to have them in the context of the code where R# is complaining.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree with your answer. If you're going to suppress issues then they deserve a comment to explain why, else just fix them and they will go away on their own.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can change the Inspection Severity under Resharper Options.

Go to Resharper -> Options -> Code Inspection -> Inspection Severity.
Find the issue and change it "Do not show".

If you have the cursor over a highlighted issue in the code window you can also press Alt-Enter to bring up a drop-down box that will allow you to change the inspection options globally.

Comment: I'd like to suppress individual instances. Not all instances of the same type.